# Sequence insert at arbitrary index implemented with Linked list

Tags: c, insert, linked-list

I'm trying to implement sequence_insert_at using the add_to_front function [here](http://ideone.com/cCWsF9)

Everything before

```
typedef struct sequence *Sequence;
```

is pasted from another c file.

```
void sequence_insert_at(Sequence s, int pos, int item)
{
    struct node* temp = s->lst;
    for(; pos > 0; --pos)
    {
        temp = temp->rest;
    }
    add_to_front(&temp, item);
    ++s->length;
    if(!temp->rest)
    {
        s->end = temp;
    }
    //s->lst = temp;
}
```

I don't know why I keep getting a runtime error. if I clone s->lst and traverse the clone, I'm not modifying the pointer to the node in s, but if I change temp, s->lst should have the reflected changes since the nodes are all linked still. Any ideas as to how to fix this? I tried creating another node that is one before the temp after traversal, and then setting it->rest = temp, but that failed as well.

Comment: how does `add_to_front` look like ?

Comment: It's in the ideone link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following mistakes a could spot but only so far to get the main function run

`new_sequence` does not initialize anything in `Sequence` it creates. `lst` is not initialized when you access it in `sequence_insert_at`

```
struct node* temp = s->lst;
```

here how it should look like

```
Sequence new_sequence()
{
    Sequence s = malloc(sizeof(struct sequence));
    if(!s)
    {
        printf("Out of memory. Can't allocate s\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    s->lst = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(! s->lst) {
        printf("Out of memory. Can't allocate lst\n");
    }
    s->lst->rest = NULL;
    s->length = 0;
    return s;
}
```

also `s->lst->rest` has to be set to `NULL`, this is what tells that the list has no more elements an not `end` witch turns obsolete.

```
struct sequence
{
    struct node* lst;
    int length;
};
```

You should be passing the sequence itself to your functions not a pointer to some internal data in the sequence.

```
add_to_front(&temp, item);
```

Your `sequence_insert_at` function should be the one that can handle any position not `add_to_front()` so it is easier to call with the position `0` from `add_to_front()` and your having the the hole work done in one function, not a half here and a half there.

```
void sequence_insert_at(Sequence s, int pos, int item)
{
    if(s && pos <= s->length) {
        print_sequence(s);
        struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (newnode == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR! add_to_front ran out of memory!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        newnode->first = item;

        struct node* temp = s->lst;
        struct node* prv = NULL;
        for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
            printf("skip %d\n", temp->first);
            prv = temp;
            temp = temp->rest;
        }
        newnode->rest = temp;
        if(pos == 0) {
            printf("insert as first\n");
            s->lst = newnode;
        } else {
            printf("insert before %d\n", temp->first);
            prv->rest = newnode;
        }

        ++s->length;
    }
}
```

and in `add_to_front` only one statement is needed

```
void add_to_front(Sequence s, int item) {
    sequence_insert_at(s, 0, item);
}
```

as for inserting at the back of the list

```
void add_to_back(Sequence s, int item) {
    sequence_insert_at(s, s->length, item);
}
```

A small test with the main function

```
void print_sequence(Sequence s)
{
    struct node* temp = s->lst;
    for(int i = 0; i < s->length; temp = temp->rest) {
        printf("%d ", temp->first);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    Sequence derp = new_sequence();
    sequence_insert_at(derp, 0, 14);
    add_to_front(derp, 16);
    sequence_insert_at(derp, 0, 17);
    sequence_insert_at(derp, 2, 15);
    add_to_back(derp, 13);
    print_sequence(derp);
    delete_sequence(derp);
    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
17 16 15 14 13
```

You'll have to go trough the other functions and fix them.

Finally i should note that variable names you have choosen are little bit confusing if not misleading, i would name them this way

```
typedef struct node {
  int data; /* the data that a node holds */
  struct node* next; /* the pointer to the next node */
} Node_t;

typedef struct sequence {
    struct node* head; /* head or first element of the sequence/list */
    int length; /* length is ok but size is better */
} Sequence_t;
```